# Orchard add string to classes

Tags: c#, orchardcms

So I gave myself a view which is overriding a parts text field. What I am trying to do is add the value of the textfield into the shape's classes.

This is the code I have at the moment in my cshtml

```
@{
    var classes = Model.Value;
    classes = classes.ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(classes))
    {
        Model.Classes.Add(classes);
    }
}
```

However when I go ahead and inspect my element the class has not been added and the class can not be found at all around the html source. Can anyone help me out.

Regards

Comment: Have you verified that this template is used? How do you render the Model?

Comment: I have added <p>DISPLAY</p> to check and it does display the rendered HTML

Comment: What is the file name and where did you put it? Did you try to attach a debugger and to put a breakpoint in there?

Comment: Yep I put a breakpoint in there and it updated Model.Classes, I put the file in the Themes folder to override the part

Comment: Can you show the rest of the template? In particular the part that is supposed to render the classes?

Comment: The code at the top was all I was using, would that not add the classes to the render call in orchards magical rendering view? :P